# Swift / Core Data / Bool or ObjCBool

Tags: core-data, swift

I'm trying to save my model with fields of type bool. When I try to add the "true" value an error occurs. 
I also tried to change the field type to Objective C Bool (ObjCBool) unsuccessfully, someone had this problem too?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Test)
class Test: NSManagedObject {
   @NSManaged var title: String
   @NSManaged var field: ObjCBool // Or Bool
}

// the error occurs before saving at this point
test.field = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution with numberWithBool:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Test)
class Test: NSManagedObject {
   @NSManaged var title: String
   @NSManaged var field: NSNumber 
}

test.field = NSNumber.numberWithBool(false)
```